# Nginx - 405 NOT ALLOWED - fastcgi timeout

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to setup a website using a synology with php 5.6 and nginx. The website is WordPress and a theme. When processing a demo import, we have a NGINX error 405 (not allowed).

It's kind of frustrating because I like when things are properly done.

I've looked in the php.ini file and the nginx.conf file.

```
# Copyright (c) 2000-2016 Synology Inc. All rights reserved.

worker_processes        auto;
#worker_cpu_affinity    auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65535;

include conf.d/main.conf;

events {
    use             epoll;
    multi_accept    on;
    worker_connections 1024;

    include conf.d/events.conf;
}

http {
    include         mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  off;
    #access_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,facility=local7,tag=nginx_access,nohostname main;
    error_log   syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,facility=local7,tag=nginx_error,nohostname error;

    sendfile        on;
    server_tokens   off;

    proxy_request_buffering     off;
    fastcgi_request_buffering   off;
    scgi_request_buffering      off;

    proxy_buffering     off;
    fastcgi_buffering   off;
    scgi_buffering      off;

    resolver_timeout              5s;
    client_header_timeout         10s;
    client_body_timeout           60s;
    send_timeout                  60s;
    keepalive_timeout             65s 20s;
    client_max_body_size          0;
    server_names_hash_max_size    8192;

    ssl_certificate           /usr/syno/etc/certificate/system/default/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /usr/syno/etc/certificate/system/default/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers               ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA;
    ssl_dhparam               /usr/syno/etc/ssl/dh2048.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    gzip_disable    "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json;
    gzip_vary       on;
    gzip_static     on;

    upstream synoscgi {
        server unix:/run/synoscgi.sock;
    }

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

    server {
        listen 5000 default_server;
        listen [::]:5000 default_server;

        server_name _;

        gzip on;

        include app.d/alias.*.conf;
        root /usr/syno/synoman;
        index index.cgi;

        ignore_invalid_headers off;

        include app.d/dsm.*.conf;
        include /usr/syno/share/nginx/conf.d/dsm.*.conf;
        include conf.d/dsm.*.conf;

        location = / {
            try_files $uri /index.cgi$is_args$query_string;
        }

        location ~ ^/volume(?:X|USB|SATA|Gluster)?\d+/ {
            internal;

            root /;

            include app.d/x-accel.*.conf;
            include conf.d/x-accel.*.conf;
        }

        location ~ /webman/modules/(PersonalSettings|ExternalDevices|FileBrowser)/index_ds.php$ {
            alias /usr/syno/share/OAuth/index_ds.php;
            default_type text/html;
        }

        location ~ \.cgi {
            include             scgi_params;
            scgi_read_timeout   3600s;
            scgi_pass           synoscgi;
        }

        error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 @error_page;

        location @error_page {
            root /usr/syno/share/nginx;
            rewrite (.*) /error.html break;
        }

        location ~ ^/webman/modules/Indexer/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/webapi/lib/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/webapi/(:?(:?.*)\.lib|(:?.*)\.api|(:?.*)\.auth|lib.def)$ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ /\. { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

        location ~* \.(?:js|css|png|jpg|gif|ico)$ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }

    }

    server {
        listen 5001 default_server ssl;
        listen [::]:5001 default_server ssl;

        server_name _;

        include app.d/alias.*.conf;
        root /usr/syno/synoman;
        index index.cgi;

        ignore_invalid_headers off;

        include app.d/dsm.*.conf;
        include /usr/syno/share/nginx/conf.d/dsm.*.conf;
        include conf.d/dsm.*.conf;

        location = / {
            try_files $uri /index.cgi$is_args$query_string;
        }

        location ~ ^/volume(?:X|USB|SATA|Gluster)?\d+/ {
            internal;

            root /;

            include app.d/x-accel.*.conf;
            include conf.d/x-accel.*.conf;
        }

        location ~ /webman/modules/(PersonalSettings|ExternalDevices|FileBrowser)/index_ds.php$ {
            alias /usr/syno/share/OAuth/index_ds.php;
            default_type text/html;
        }

        location ~ \.cgi {
            include             scgi_params;
            scgi_read_timeout   3600s;
            scgi_pass           synoscgi;
        }

        error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 @error_page;

        location @error_page {
            root /usr/syno/share/nginx;
            rewrite (.*) /error.html break;
        }

        location ~ ^/webman/modules/Indexer/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/webapi/lib/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/webapi/(:?(:?.*)\.lib|(:?.*)\.api|(:?.*)\.auth|lib.def)$ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ /\. { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

        location ~* \.(?:js|css|png|jpg|gif|ico)$ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }

    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;

        server_name _;

        location ~ ^/volume(?:X|USB|SATA|Gluster)?\d+/ {
            internal;

            root /;

            include app.d/x-accel.*.conf;
            include conf.d/x-accel.*.conf;
        }

        include app.d/www.*.conf;
        include app.d/alias.*.conf;
        include /usr/syno/share/nginx/conf.d/www.*.conf;
        include conf.d/www.*.conf;

        location = /webman/pingpong.php {
            rewrite /webman/pingpong.php /webman/pingpong.cgi break;

            root /usr/syno/synoman;
            include scgi_params;
            scgi_pass synoscgi;
        }

        location = /webdefault/images/logo.jpg {
            alias /usr/syno/share/nginx/logo.jpg;
        }

        error_page 405 =200 $uri;

        location ~* \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }


        error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 @error_page;

        location @error_page {
            root /usr/syno/share/nginx;
            rewrite (.*) /error.html break;
        }

        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
            root /var/lib/letsencrypt;
            default_type text/plain;
        }

        include app.d/.location.webstation.conf*;

        location ~ ^/$ {

            if ($scheme = https) {
                rewrite / https://$host:5001/ redirect;
            }

            rewrite / http://$host:5000/ redirect;

        }
    }

    include conf.d/http.*.conf;
    include app.d/server.*.conf;
    include sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I've searched a lot on internet and so far only some interesting leads but nothing worked.

I've tried to add the following to the nginx.conf (that's why my actual nginx.conf has those lines) but it didn't solved my problem.

```
location ~* \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

For information, here is the error in log file :

> 2017/02/10 18:14:07 [error] 18555#18555: *2563 upstream timed out
>   (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from
>   upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "POST
>   /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/php56-fpm.sock", host: "www.example.com",
>   referrer:
>   http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=laborator-demo-content-installer&install-pack=agency&

If you have any idea to solve this problem... because I've been struggling since some weeks now...
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Have you been able to get this resolved? I am experiencing the same issue and after a week or so of searching I ended up here...

Comment: @LukeP see my answer. If it still won't work, please post the gist of your error_page directives, as they are key to this.

Comment: @mknecht Thanks. I got it working in the end. Can't remember what it was but it was specific to my environment. I'm running ResourceSpace DAM on Synology NAS and the config is managed by Synology DSM that would replace the configuration changes I made everytime I restarted the web server to apply them.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr—Your WordPress is too slow. Jump to the bottom to see how you can make NGINX return you the proper `504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT` status code.

The longer version: You have a bunch of separate issues working together in an unhelpful way.

**1. WordPress, your upstream server, is not responding fast enough**

It takes longer than 4 minutes, that's why you see a `110: Connection timed out` in your logs. The **solution to the slowness** is to speed up WordPress. As a workaround, you could give it more time to process the request. To do that, increase the number in your `fastcgi_read_timeout 240;` rule. Note that the timeout is given in seconds, so if you're fine with waiting 10 minutes, set this to `600`.

I'd advise against increasing the timeout, though. You should really address the performance issue itself. Such long requests block resources in NGINX and WordPress, and therefore allow you to be DDoSed quite easily, even accidentally by yourself.

Because your upstream takes too long, NGINX would respond with a `504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT`. It cannot because…

**2. POST requests cannot be answered with static files**

In your `error_page` location, you're telling NGINX to use static files to handle the requests. That's fine for `GET` or `HEAD`, but it does not work for `POST`, because it would ask NGINX to overwrite/create files. That's neither intended nor supported by NGINX. (The request would also fail using other modifying verbs such as `PUT` and `DELETE`, for the same reason.)

Note that you are using a named location, `@error_page`, for which the [method remains POST, as the manual says](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page):

```
If there is no need to change URI and method during internal redirection it is possible to pass error processing into a named location.
```

You already know part of this, which is why you added the `error_page 405 =200 $uri;` rule. Unfortunately, this did not save you, because…

**3. Internal error_page redirects are not recursive by default**

This is not mentioned in the documentation for the  `error_page` manual, as far as I can see, but it *is* mentioned in the docs of the following directive:

**Workaround: Enable recursive error_page redirects**

The directive [recursive_error_pages](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#recursive_error_pages) allows you to handle errors that occur *while* a previous error is being handled. From the docs:

```
 Enables or disables doing several redirects using the error_page directive. The number of such redirects is limited.
```

If you enable this, by putting `recursive_error_pages  on;` into your server block, you'll allow the `error_page 405` directive to kick in.

Unfortunately, since you're still requesting the same resource with your `$uri` part, WordPress will be queried again for the same URL, this time with a GET request. No idea how your WordPress handles that, but chances are the error that will occur then will not help you to debug this.

This really is just jumping around the problem; what you should get is the original `504`. Therefore, I suggest you do the following, instead of enabling recursive error page redirects:

**Solution: Use `GET` to fetch your error pages**

I assume you still want to return your error.html even on a POST request. For that you need to force NGINX to drop the `POST` and handle the error with `GET`, so that static files can be used. The only way I've found to make this happen is to not use a named location (the ones with `@` at the beginning), but an [internal](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) one instead.

To use this option, change your `@error_page` location to include a pseudo-path and the `internal` directive, for example like so:

```
    location /error_page {
        internal;
        root /usr/syno/share/nginx;
        rewrite (.*) /error.html break;
    }
```

Afterwards, modify the `error_page` directive, to use the new location:

```
    error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error_page;
```

Resources: [A helpful discussion on the NGINX mailing list.](http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/quot-error-page-quot-amp-quot-return-quot-bug-td7298436.html)

Comment: I summarized the gotchas above, and others I encountered re the error_page directive in this blog post, hopefully it's helpful to someone (probably me in the future): http://muratknecht.de/tech/why-nginx-returns-405-post-504-gateway-timeout-gotchas-error-page/